# How can create this design the background color decoration

Tags: flutter, dart, figma

[image: Login Page]

How to design that page I want to design it by using container. I just want to change the background color of this Flutter application. Please let me know how to do that in flutter application. or i use a picture in background with some opacity of the image.

Comment: Try `ClipPath` or `CustomPaint`

Comment: You can add the image in `decoration` of `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Davis comment. Using a custom clip path can help you achieve the desired output in your design. Please see the documents below. I'm sure this will help you!

Reference 1: [Ultimate guide to Flutter Clipping Widgets](https://akshaymkkr.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-flutter-clipping-widgets-41272d298dee)

Reference 2: [How to make Bezier Curve waves using custom clip Path in Flutter](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/36/how-to-make-bezier-curve-waves-using-custom-clip-path-in-flutter/)